# Is it possible to pass an integer with leading zeros through a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a function that accepts an integer value and returns another integer value. Sometimes the input value can have a leading zero.

I've tried changing the input to a string type and the code works perfectly, but it's essential for me to make sure the input type is of integer.

```
def my_function(input):
    string_count = str(input)
    count = int(string_count)
    count_length = len(string_count)
    count_integer_list = [int(d) for d in str(count)]
    new_count_integer_list = []
    total = 0
    new_total = 0
    for number in count_integer_list:
        total += number
    if count_length <= 0 or count_length >= 15:
        return -1
    else:
        while total != new_total:
            new_total = 0
            count += 1
            new_count_integer_list = [int(d) for d in str(count)]
            for number in new_count_integer_list:
                new_total += number
        if count_length < len(str(count)):
            return -1
        elif len(str(count)) < count_length:
            return str(count).zfill(count_length)
        else:
            return count;

print(my_function(0200))
```

This is the error I get:

```
print(my_function(0200))
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: What? Where is that actually coming from? `0200` simply isn't a valid literal in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3127

Comment: Um, that is source code, an `int` literal. Just don't write that, because that isn't valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass something that does not exist.

The binary encoding of an integer in python does not include leading zeros. The concept of leading zeros purely stylistic, 002 and 2 have the same numerical value. And Python's integer representation does not include any style, only the value.

Therefore python decided to forbid int literals with leading zeros in the first place, so `0200` is invalid code.

Therefore, to answer your question: Just don't worry about it. There are no integers with leading zeros.

This statement is incorrect:

> Sometimes the input value can have a leading zero.

Comment: The way integers are encoded isn't really relevant, there is nothing in principle preventing the python parser from accepting an integer literal with leading zeroes. It simply doesn't.

Comment: The Python 2 parser *did*, in fact, just as octals not decimals.

Comment: @Finomnis yes, so what?

Comment: That's only true from zero to seven, anyway; the OP's example is `0200`, which is `128` in Python 2. Python's integers abstract away from the underlying representation, e.g. allowing arbitrary precision, so talking about two's complement is not particularly relevant; that's now how you deal with numbers in Python (look at e.g. `format(-2, 'b')`!)

Comment: @Finomnis what? Why does the function have to tell the difference? *That isn't the issue*. It is completely irrelevant. That could have been a totally valid integer literal. It simply isn't as a design choice, not because of the underlying representation.

Comment: I apologize, you are absolutely right. Python doesn't even encode numbers in the 2-complement, therefore my example is stupid. Thanks for pointing out, I rephrased my argument.